# Hostname problem with Wildfly 10 and RabbitMQ JDNI configuration

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jms, message-queue, jndi

I'm following this documentation to configure JNDI for Wildfly 10 with RabbitMQ

https://www.rabbitmq.com/jms-client.html

The reason i'm using JNDI is to my application has no dependency with any JMS Provider's library. It means, in my application, i use javax.jms-api-2.0.jar only for integration with RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ... later.

This is my configuration in Wildfly standalone.xml file.

```
                <object-factory name="java:global/jms/ConnectionFactory1" module="com.rabbitmq.jms" 
                    class="com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQObjectFactory">
                    <environment>
                        <property name="className" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
                        <property name="virtualHost" value="/"/>
                        <property name="host" value="rabbitmq_server"/>
                        <property name="port" value="5672"/>
                    </environment>
                </object-factory>
```

This is the soure code for integration.

```
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory
                    = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:global/jms/ConnectionFactory1");
            if (connectionFactory == null) {
                System.out.println("Cannot initiallize connection factory.");
                return;
            }
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(
                    "guest",
                    "guest");
            
            if (connection == null) {
                System.out.println("Initiallize connection failed.");
                return;
            }
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            if (session == null) {
                System.out.println("Initiallize session failed.");
                return;
            }
```

My problem is:
At this configuration,

1. If i set the value is IP address => it is ok
2. If I set the value is hostname (already mapping with IP address in my hosts file) => it always create connection to localhost.

Anyone has faced with this issue before?

```
12:00:12,318 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) com.rabbitmq.jms.util.RMQJMSException: RabbitMQ connection was refused. RabbitMQ broker may not be available.

12:00:12,319 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQConnectionFactory.instantiateNodeConnection(RMQConnectionFactory.java:170)

12:00:12,319 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(RMQConnectionFactory.java:117)

12:00:12,319 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.mypackage.web.servlet.WhiteListRegistration.test(WhiteListRegistration.java:68)

12:00:12,320 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.mypackage.web.servlet.WhiteListRegistration.processRequest(WhiteListRegistration.java:106)

12:00:12,320 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.mypackage.web.servlet.WhiteListRegistration.doPost(WhiteListRegistration.java:180)

12:00:12,320 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)

12:00:12,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

12:00:12,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

12:00:12,321 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

12:00:12,322 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

12:00:12,322 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

12:00:12,323 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

12:00:12,323 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

12:00:12,324 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

12:00:12,325 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

12:00:12,325 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

12:00:12,326 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

12:00:12,326 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

12:00:12,327 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

12:00:12,327 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

12:00:12,327 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

12:00:12,327 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

12:00:12,328 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

12:00:12,328 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

12:00:12,328 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

12:00:12,329 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)

12:00:12,380 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

12:00:12,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)

12:00:12,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)

12:00:12,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

12:00:12,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

12:00:12,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

12:00:12,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

12:00:12,381 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

12:00:12,382 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

12:00:12,382 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

12:00:12,382 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)

12:00:12,383 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

12:00:12,383 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)

12:00:12,384 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)

12:00:12,384 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)

12:00:12,385 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

12:00:12,386 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

12:00:12,387 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

12:00:12,391 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

12:00:12,392 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

12:00:12,393 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)

12:00:12,394 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)

12:00:12,394 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

12:00:12,394 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)

12:00:12,396 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

12:00:12,397 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)

12:00:12,398 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)

12:00:12,398 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)

12:00:12,398 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:156)

12:00:12,398 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1106)

12:00:12,399 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1063)

12:00:12,434 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1021)

12:00:12,434 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1182)

12:00:12,435 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   at com.rabbitmq.jms.admin.RMQConnectionFactory.instantiateNodeConnection(RMQConnectionFactory.java:159)

12:00:12,435 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15)   ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya, i just found out that the hostname cannot contains some special character such as _.
Then i removed this from rabbitmq_server to rabbitmqserver then everything is good now.

Hope someone get the issue like me can fix it follow this.